# How to iterate over an Aws::Crt::Map in C++

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I'm using AWS IoT C++ Device SDK and I need to iterate over an `Aws::Crt::Map`, but i can't find any iterators. Nor iterator or Iterator appears to exist.

```
Map<String, JsonView>::Iterator it;

error: ‘Iterator’ is not a member of 
Aws::Crt::Map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
Aws::Crt::StlAllocator<char> >, Aws::Crt::JsonView>’ `
```

Basically I need to iterate over all values in my current Json Node but i can only get that as `Aws::Crt::Map` and i don't seem to be able to iterate through that. Any suggestions on how i can achieve this?

Many thanks,
Marcus

Comment: What about `auto it = `

Comment: @Marcin, thanks! It appears that did it! Bit rusty on my C++ so not used to using auto.